# How to combine mergeMap observables calls and return just one value for the whole observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have this scenario in typescript/angular with rxjs 6.5:

```
   main(){

        const properties = ['session', 'user'];
        const source: Observable<any> = from(properties);

        source
            .pipe(
                mergeMap(key => this.getKey().map((value) => ({key: key, value: value}))),
                tap((result) => {
                    // sending the result elsewhere;
                }),
            ).subscribe(
            (result) => {
                console.log('Final result ->', result);
            }
        );

        console.log('\n');

    }

    getKey(): Observable<any> {
        // Mock function that returns an observable that emits 1 value
        const observable = from(['test']);

        return observable;
    }
```

The output is:

```
Final result -> {key: "session", value: "test"}
Final result -> {key: "user", value: "test"}
```

**1st question:**
How do I return, **in the most elegant way**, upon subscription on source, just 1 value, with the combined results of the inner observables?

My wanted output, with the subscription in this way (because I want this combined operation to be in the pipe), would be:

```
(...).subscribe(
(result) => {console.log('Final Result:', result}
)

OUTPUT:

Final result -> [{key: "session", value: "test"}, {key: "user", value: "test"}]
```

**2nd question**
If I don't care about the result of the inner observables, how do I return just 1 value or how do I know when all the inner observables have been completed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Q1:** You need a **[`toArray`](https://thinkrx.io/rxjs/toArray/)** — it will combine all your stream values into one array:

[image: toArray example]

**Q2:** To omit all values on the stream and emit a value upon completion

```js
concat(
  source$.pipe(ignoreElements()),
  of(true)
)
```

[image: emit a value upon source completion]

See ["**Emit a value upon source completion**"](https://thinkrx.io/gist/701c9bfc4497701321bc85b936b5f193) example in a playground

Comment: That's super simple and direct, and it does solve the first question, for sure in one line.

Comment: @Martin as for the second question — its not clear what you're looking for. `toArray` returns values when source completes. Also there are `first`, `last`, `take(n)` to get particular items from the stream. Theres `finalize` to do side-effects upon completion. You could also `ignoreElements` and then `concat` another observable on the source if you only care about source completion. Lots of options :)

Comment: For my second question, what I am after is just to listen to completion. While, with toArray I get just 1 emmited value with all those values, which is great. But if I don't care about the emmited inner values and just want to receive a "true" when everything completes, how would you do it in an elegant way as well?.

Comment: I know I could then use, after the toArray(), a map(result=> true), but I want to avoid the toArray, for the sake of optimisation. 

If there is a way, to avoid the processing that toArray does, and then just get a true, when all the inner observables complete, that is what I am looking for, in order to learn.

Thanks.

Comment: @Martin, for one you can subscribe to particularly completion: `.subscribe({ complete: ()=>console.log('done')})`. If you need a `true` on stream, then `.pipe( ignoreElements(), concat(from([ true ])) )`

Comment: @Martin, also, just for learning sake: check out a more sophisticated [`dematerialize`](https://observable-playground.github.io/rxjs/dematerialize/) — it will turn technical rxjs events into ordinary events. So you could `filter` completion event and then `mapTo(true)` it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192626/discussion-between-martin-and-kos).

Answer (score 10):

To get combined result of all response of mergeMap, you can also try like this:

```
return this.request1().pipe(
  mergeMap(res1=> this.request2(res1.id).pipe(
    map(res2=> {
      return {
        res1: res1,
        res2: res2
      }
    })
  ))
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an annotated example to help clarify your questions on the subscription process you ask about.

**Q1:**

As pointed out in another answer, the `reduce` operator is what you'll want to include in your `source` pipeline. A key detail with `reduce` is that it only emits upon completion of the corresponding source observable. If instead you want emission as those inner observables complete, then `scan` is appropriate. Another difference with the latter is that it doesn't require source completion.

**Q2:**

With this question, refer to my example below and think of each argument to the processing pipeline as the lifetime of a single request. Here, completion is implicit. It occurs after the last value of the inner observables is processed.

However, if there's no bound to inner observables, then knowing when all the inner observables are complete isn't possible. In such a case, you'll find that `reduce()` won't work.

```js
const { from, of, Subject } = rxjs;
const { mergeMap, map, tap, reduce, scan } = rxjs.operators;

// Use a subject to simulate processing.
// Think of each argument as a request to the processing pipeline below.
const properties = new Subject();

// Establish processing pipeline
const source = properties.pipe(
  // `mergeMap` here flattens the output value to the combined inner output values
  mergeMap(props =>
    // Each item inside the argument should be piped as separate values
    from(props).pipe(
      // `mergeMap` here flattens the output value to `{ key, value }`
      mergeMap(key =>
        of('test').pipe(
          map(value => ({ key, value })),
        ),
      ),
      // Unlike `scan`, `reduce` only emits upon "completion".
      // Here, "completion" is implicit - it is after the last
      // element of `from(props)` has been processed.
      reduce((a, i) => [...a, i], []),
    )
  ),  
);

// Subscribe to the pipeline to observe processing.
source.subscribe(console.log);

// Trigger a processing request with an argument
properties.next(['session', 'user']);

// Trigger another processing request
properties.next(['session', 'user']);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.5.1/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use reduce

```
.pipe(
  reduce((results, result) => {
    results.push(result);
    return results;
  }, [])
)
```

The resulting observable will only emit once all the others have emitted and the emitted value will be an array of all the results.

Comment: If I add this, i get a tslint error saying S2345: Argument of type 'MonoTypeOperatorFunction<any[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<{ key: any; value: any; }, any[]>

Where exactly would you attatch that pipe? After my initial one?, I also tried to add reduce inside the current pipe, after the mergemap, but still get tslint errors.

Comment: pipe is a method on the observable

Comment: Yes, yes. I know that. But in my particular example, adding reduce, while keeping mergemap and tap, doesn't compile:

source
   .pipe(
    mergeMap(key => this.storage.get(key).map((value) => ({key: key, value: value}))),
    tap((result) => {
     this.app_data[result.key] = result.value;
    }), 
reduce((results, result) => {
    results.push(result);
    return results;
  }, [])
    
   );

Answer (score 0):

1st Question, you can use `scan` to handle and accumulate output

```
 mergeMap(key => from(this.getKey())),
 scan((acc,curr) =>acc.concat([{key: curr.key, value: curr.value}]),[])),
```

2n Question

use `first()` operator to take just one output from inner observable
attach `finalize()` to the inner observable which will be trigger when inner observable complete. or use `last()` to get the last accumulated result

```
 mergeMap(key => from(this.getKey())),
 scan((acc,curr) =>acc.concat([{key: curr.key, value: curr.value}]),[])),
 first()
```

Comment: Scan emits the accumulator every time the scanned observable emits, reduce only emits once as the reduced observable completes which is what OP is looking for.

Comment: You are correct. Can also use last() to emit last result.